# How do I report a bug in Windows Server Service Bus?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azureservicebus, servicebus, mscorlib

I tried to google. Microsoft Connect doesn't accept bugs for Service Bus. Azure Portal sends to either MS forums or to StackOverflow - so here I am.

The question is really in the title: **how do I report a bug with Service Bus?**
(not the Azure version, but the one you install on premises)

## And here is the issue:

1. `Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.dll` has a reference to `Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll`. It uses one type from that assembly - namely, `StorageAccountInfo`. It's part of a configuration section (namely, `NamespacePolicyDataStoreFactorySection.Parameters.BlobStorageAccountInfo`), but apparently only makes sense in the Azure environment, and never used in the on-premise scenario.
2. But here's the catch: `Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll` is not actually shipped with Service Bus 1.1. I tried to find it in various SDKs and Azure toolkits, samples and whatnot (of which I have plenty), as well as online - and found zippo information about that DLL or where to get it. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mandi/archive/2014/12/02/dear-messagesender-exe-we-re-breaking-up.aspx) is the only place I found a mention of it.
3. Despite being a WTF in itself, the absence of DLL does not really prevent anything from working: the type is not actually touched by any code in the on-premise scenario, so no complaints.
4. But here's the second catch: `mscorlib.dll` v4.6.7.0 (which came with VS2015 CTP5) has a slight change compared to the previous version, 4.0.30319.34014, - in `System.Attribute.InternalGetCustomAttributes(PropertyInfo,Type,bool)`, more precisely, [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Attribute.cs#L46). That line did not exist in the previous version of `mscorlib`, and everything was fine. But now it does exist, which leads to the property type being *touched*, which leads to loading the DLL, which fails, because DLL is not there.
5. So the whole process starts with loading configuration section `NamespacePolicyDataStoreFactorySection` and works like this:

---

```
  ConfigurationManager.GetSection -> 
  ... -> 
  BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive -> 
  ... -> 
  BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection -> 
  MgmtConfigurationRecord.CreateSection -> 
  ConfigurationElement.Reset -> 
  ConfigurationElement.get_Properties -> 
  ConfigurationElement.PropertiesFromType -> 
  ConfigurationElement.CreatePropertyBagFromType -> 
  Attribute.GetCustomAttribute (for property BlobStorageAccountInfo of type StorageAccountInfo) ->
  ... ->
  Attribute.InternalGetCustomAttributes(PropertyInfo) ->
  Attributes.GetIndexParameterTypes ->
  RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters ->
  ... ->
  RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters ->
  ... ->
  kaboom! (touches the return type, tries to load DLL containing it, fails)
```

## Some (futile) attempts at a workaround

1. Remove the configuration section from config. Unfortunately, Service Bus is not very fault tolerant in this respect: fails with NRE when section is not present. It is also impossible to provide an alternative config section "handler", because in the .NET config system "handler" and "data" are the same thing.
2. Provide a fake DLL with the needed type. Can't do that, because everything is strongly named.
3. Find the missing DLL somewhere. Tried that and failed. There are no mentions of the DLL on the web, let alone the bits.

A careful reader may ask: whoa, wait a minute! VS2015 CTP5?! Are you saying you installed pre-release software on a working machine?! Well then, of course it doesn't work, what did you expect? That'll teach you to be the early adopter!
And the careful reader would be absolutely correct: totally my fault, I knew potential dangers, I did it anyway, serves me right.

But that's not the point. My installing pre-release software doesn't diminish the WTFness of referencing a DLL, but not shipping it. While I personally will be fine, I just want to make sure this doesn't suddenly stop working when .NET 5 is released and hits Windows Update.

Comment: `But that's not the point.` The point is you don't know how to report a bug/ who to contact for a software product...

Comment: I reached out to Microsoft about this issue and they [directed me to this](http://smallbusiness.support.microsoft.com/en-US/contact?Ocid=1.%20Owned%20NA%20(Reactive)_Social_TWITTER_MicrosoftHelps_20150213_144107951&linkId=12336486). There you should be able to contact them, or at the very least get in a chat with them to report the bug.

Comment: But that's support for small business, isn't it? I'll try this, but are you sure I'll be able to do it without having a small business account?

Comment: Microsoft said that was where to go to report a bug with the Windows Server Service Bus. I tried and you can start a chat without any accounts (besides a Microsoft account) I'm not sure if that is the end goal or if they will try to redirect you somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, that was so very not a success. When I opened the chat, the person on the other side told me that I reached Office 365 University Verification team (whatever that is), but she was helpful enough to dig up a phone number for Professional Support for me. After spending about 30 minutes on various holds and redirects, I finally gave up after failing to even get the people on the other side to understand the word "bug", let alone "Service Bus". They just kept asking: "...and you want to report a box?"

Comment: Try pinging the Azure team on Twitter. Sometimes they can be very responsive and point you in the right direction. Or you can always try Small Business Support. I've heard that they are great solving boxes.

Comment: Utter failure Microsoft. Way to be a faceless corp.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know it's a late answer to the question and it is actually not the answer to the question asked, but today, after installing VS 2015 RC on a PC with Windows Service Bus 1.1 and restarting the PC, my service bus gateway service stopped working and I went through all the pain described in this question but finally could make a solution out of the fake assembly scenario. Here's the solution:

1. Created the fake assembly Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll with version 2.1.0.0 and signed it with a new key file.
2. Disassembled it using: ildasm /all /out=azurestorage.il Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll
3. Extracted the public key and public key token from another Microsoft.Cloud.* assembly located in service bus folder by ildasm /Tp Microsoft.Cloud.Common.Diagnostics.dll
4. Opened azurestorage.il in a text editor and changed the public-key token and public key with the ones extracted in the last step
5. Reassembled the il file: ilasm /dll azurestorage.il /out=Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll
6. Registered the assembly for signature verification skipping using: sn -Vr Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll
7. Installed the resulting assembly to GAC: gacutil /i Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll

and it finally worked. Hope this helps anyone who got stuck in this problem.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Can you share your fake assembly please?

Comment: Shared it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb5fro1rvg4dbvu/Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll?dl=1   using this assembly, you just have to go through steps 6 and 7.

Comment: I wanted to make sure I didn't forget where this is and how to fix it so I've added your solution to Github - https://github.com/matthewcanty/Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.FAKE.dll

Comment: Upgraded my development machine to Windows 10. Two problems: AppFabric Cache didn't start (needed Remote Registry Service to run) and the Service Bus didn't start. This fake solved my problem for the service bus!

Answer (score 3):

As given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716273/azure-service-bus-1-1-failing-to-start) by Jafin there is fortunately an official fix from Microsoft release 10/23/2015 that solves the issue with .NET 4.6.

Download here: [Update for Service Bus Server 1.1 (KB3086798)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49496)

Answer (score -2):

as I understand what you need is reporting a bug to Microsoft, and I found out you need to report a bug to Microsoft. Its good to know microsoft will aapriceate users who report bugs.

According to Microsoft answer you can reporting Microsfot bugs here:https://connect.microsoft.com/

*note: You must have an microsoft account, you can make it at **hotmail.com***

And I know some of microsoft products are not there like outlook.com

First go to https://connect.microsoft.com/ :

---

### STEP BY STEP

i.stack.imgur.com/CewDL.png

Step 1: Write the program what you like to report a bug about it, and then click on join.

---

i.stack.imgur.com/pJbQY.png

Step 2: Click on continue.

---

i.stack.imgur.com/cCgXq.png

Step 3: Make up your profile.

---

i.stack.imgur.com/PVqXi.png

Step 4: Click on feedback.

---

i.stack.imgur.com/nL5Kr.png

Step 5: Write the bug title on text box at the end of page.

---

i.stack.imgur.com/gEOJG.png

Step 6: Then click on **submit feedback**

---

i.stack.imgur.com/MQgV0.png

Step 7: Now you can write the problem and tell Microsoft about this bug.

Comment: Please copy image url and see them

Comment: Really? Have you read the question? It mentions MS Connect right at the beginning.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thats only way what I know to report a bug to Microsoft