# Azure Service Bus 1.1 Failing to Start

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus

Service Bus Gateway is not starting.

First of all I have tried completely uninstalling all Azure/Fabric/Service Bus type SDKs and installations. I have installed both `Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1` and `Windows Azure Pack: Security Update for Service Bus 1.1 (KB2972621)` from scratch.

After deleting all service bus related databases I start the Service Bus Configuration wizard and begin starting a new farm with custom settings.

I leave everything default except adding my own certificates, and of course entering my password.

After clicking go the the service bus configuration wizard eventually gets stuck *in progress*:

```
Starting
Created and configured Service Bus farm management database.
Created and configured Service Bus gateway database.
Creating default container.

Processing completed
Validating input and configuration parameters.
Granting 'Log on as Service' privilege to the run as account.
Windows Fabric configuration started.
Running Windows Fabric deployment.
Windows Fabric starting.
Service Bus configuration started.
Updating database.
Service Bus services starting.
```

The event viewer logs for `Microsoft-Service Bus > Operational` has the following errors. Top error received first...

```
Exception during fabric service creation for container 1, Exception System.ArgumentException: At least one address must be provided if hostEndpoints is non-null
Parameter name: hostEndpoints
   at System.Fabric.FabricClient.InitializeFabricClient(SecurityCredentials credential, TimeSpan keepAliveInterval, String[] hostEndpoints)
   at System.Fabric.FabricClient..ctor(SecurityCredentials credential, String[] hostEndpoints)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.ServiceBusGetCommands.CreateFabricClient()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.ServiceBusCommandBase.RegisterWinFabricService(Int64 containerId)
```

And then:

```
Service Bus Gateway service failed to start, retry count 1.  Exception message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for namespacePolicyDataStoreFactory: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4fe77f22fa8374f3' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..  Stack Trace:    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader, String filename, Int32 line)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionDefault(String configKey, Boolean getRuntimeObject, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.ServiceRegistryManagerContext.CreateNamespacePolicyDataManager(IComponentSite site)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.ServiceRegistryManagerContext.LoadServices(IComponentSite site)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.Common.Components.ComponentFactoryBase`1.CreateComponent()
   at Microsoft.Cloud.HostingModel.ComponentHost.CreateComponent(IComponentFactory componentFactory)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.HostingModel.ComponentHost.CreateComponents()
   at Microsoft.Cloud.HostingModel.ComponentHost.Open()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Gateway.Gateway.OnStart(String[] args)
```

In Services the relevant services have the following statuses:

- Service Bus Gateway: Starting
- Service Bus Message Broker: Stopped
- Service Bus Resource Provider: Stopped

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you received this error after updating to NET framework v4.6+ then 
Microsoft have a fix for this now, download this  Update for Service Bus Server 1.1 (KB3086798)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49496

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR;**

1. Download [dropbox.com/s/cb5fro1rv...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb5fro1rvg4dbvu/Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll?dl=1) - *thanks [Arash Rahimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4931970/arash-rahimi)*
2. Navigate to your SDK tools
3. `sn -Vr Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll`
4. `gacutil /i Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll`

This issue was caused by installing the Visual Studio 2015 RC. Thankfully someone else has already experienced this and an answer has been posted.

Please see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30413095/966609) on [How do I report a bug in Windows Server Service Bus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333034/how-do-i-report-a-bug-in-windows-server-service-bus)

For whatever reason if the Dropbox link becomes obsolete. I have [added it to Github](https://github.com/matthewcanty/Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.FAKE.dll).

Comment: 5. added an IISReset

not sure whether it's necessary or not. But I did and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any/all RabbitMQ service(s) are all stopped. (Or anything that uses the AMQP protocol)