# Configuring Service Bus for Windows - cannot start Service Bus Gateway

Tags: c#, servicebus

I am trying to configure the service bus for windows but at the stage of Add Host to Service Bus Farm it fails starting the Service Bus Gateway.

In the event log it states:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4fe77f22fa8374f3' or one of its dependencies.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have the Azure SDK installed? it may be a pre-req?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue Gary F. It's driving me insane.

Comment: I have installed the Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2015) - 2.7.1 it this the one I may need?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is an issue with VS 2015 and Service bus hosted locally. It may well be that you are having a slightly different issue from what I was just having, but I found another post, ran through the steps and it seems to have resolved my issues.

Have a look through [How do I report a bug in Windows Server Service Bus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333034/how-do-i-report-a-bug-in-windows-server-service-bus)

The summary is

1. you need to download the dll that Arash has provided [in this drop box link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb5fro1rvg4dbvu/Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll?dl=1).
2. Paste the file into your SDK Tools folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64)
3. open up command prompt in Admin mode
4. run command `sn -Vr Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll`
5. then run the command `gacutil /i Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.dll`

Let me know how you get on...

Comment: Yeah thanks Nav. I found this recently and it worked for me. I'm not sure if we could get around the verification skipping though for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after installing Visual Studio 2015 in windows server 2008 R2 which has the .Net 4.6 framework. 
I found the update for Service Bus 1.1 here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49496

After installing above, rebooted the machine as prompted and attempted to start the Service Bus Gateway - worked like a charm!!

Comment: This is the proper solution and considerably safer than installing a "fake dll" from an independent source.